# How many baskets of n fruits can be formed that contains at most 3 apples, even number of pears, and any number of oranges and plums?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, generating-functions

My attempt:

$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 = n$

So the generating function

$g(x) = (1+x+x^2+x^3)(1+x^2+x^4+...)(1+x+x^2+x^3+...)(1+x+x^2+x^3+...)$

$g(x) = \frac{1-x^4}{1-x}\frac{1}{1-x^2}\frac{1}{1-x}\frac{1}{1-x}$

$g(x) = \frac{1+x^2}{(1-x)^3}$

Comment: I dont see any purpose of the middle part of your solution. Your resultant $g(x)$ is correct and finding the coefficient of the $x^n$ term should give you the correct answer.

Comment: I think he don’t know the formula of expansion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can proceed further and using the binomial theorem find the closed form of the answer:
$$
[x^n]\frac{1+x^2}{(1-x)^3}=[x^n](1+x^2)\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{-3}k(-x)^k=
[x^n](1+x^2)\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{k+2}2x^k=
\binom{n+2}2+\binom n2,
$$
where $[x^n]$ is the coefficient extractor, which gives the coefficient at $x^n$ in the series expansion of the following expression.

Above we used the identity:
$$
\binom{-n}k=(-1)^k\binom{n+k-1}k=(-1)^k\binom{n+k-1}{n-1}.
$$

Comment: @drstress See my edit.

Comment: It is better to write $x_1+2x_2+x_3+x_4=n$.

Comment: $$0\le 2x_2\le n$$

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: I have no objection.

Comment: $$(1+x^2)x^k=x^k+x^{k+2}$$ due to distributive law of multiplication.